# Play animation every 15 second css

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animation that will run infinite time every 15second.
Also, I want to play the animation in this order -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 (need to animation items back)
Every animation has a different delay.
Can it possible with CSS? Animation delay is working only on the first iteration.
When animation time is long it is easy to achieve this effect, but with 1s or smaller can't find a good way.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 6px;
  animation: glow .7s alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;
  }
}

.item1 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.item2 {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

.item3 {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.item4 {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item1'></div>
  <div class='item2'></div>
  <div class='item3'></div>
  <div class='item4'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, you don't need Javascript for this. It can be a pure CSS animation. However, I don't quite understand what combination you want as your animation goes both 'forwards and backwards' AND hhas alternate- set. Should the 'lights' just 'glow' then fade out in 0.7seconds and do this every 15 seconds (with delays so they don't do it all at the same time)?

Comment: Animation time should be 0.7second(very fast). I need 2 things todo.
1.Run animation every 15second (from left to right, animation count should be infinite.
2. Change animation a little bit, need to run from left to right then forward from right to left without stoping, and stop 15second then run again and so on.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure what's meant by 'change the animation a little bit'. What has to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It may help you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 6px;
}

@keyframes glow1 {
  0%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  1% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  2%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  3%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  3%,9%,13%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  10%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  11% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  12%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  99%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  100%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
}
@keyframes glow2 {
  0%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  1% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  2%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  3%,7%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  8%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  9% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  10%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  11%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  99%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  100%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
}
@keyframes glow3 {
  0%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  1% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  2%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  3%,5%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  6%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  7% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  8%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  9%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  99%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  100%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
}
@keyframes glow4 {
  0%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  1% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  2%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  3%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  4%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  5% {box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px black;}
  6%{ box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
  7%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  99%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;}
  100%{box-shadow: 0 0 -6px -6px black;}
}

.item1 {
  animation: glow1 10s linear 1s infinite;
}

.item2 {
  animation: glow2 10s linear 1.1s infinite;
}

.item3 {
  animation:glow3 10s linear 1.2s infinite;
}

.item4 {
  animation:glow4 10s linear 1.3s infinite;  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="div1" class='item1'></div>
  <div id="div2" class='item2'></div>
  <div id="div3" class='item3'></div>
  <div id="div4" class='item4'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do this with only css (